# Validate registration user in web app (spring-boot + AngularJS)

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, spring-boot, repository

I am implementing a web project in spring boot + date + AngularJS. Client side (angularjs) makes requests to the Rest server (spring-boot). Spring boot using repositories to develop search the database of CrudRepository.

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface ClientRepository  extends CrudRepository< Client , Integer > { 

    List< Client > findAll( );

}
```

Only need to edit the save function of the repository. I tried to create a service layer that runs up the save but is not working.

```
@Component( "clientService" )
@Transactional
public class ClientRepositoryImpl implements ClientService{

    private final ClientRepository clientRepository;

    public ClientRepositoryImpl( ClientRepository clientRepository ) {
        this.clientRepository = clientRepository;
    }


    @Override
    public String addClient( Client saved ) {
            // ....
            if( this.clientRepository.save( saved ) != null )
                return "OK";
            else 
                return "NOK";

    }  

}
```

Can anyone give an idea how I can create some logic before invoking the save repository? I'm implementing the registration and need to validate the data entered on the server side and do not know validate before the repository to save. Since the client side make a call rest (/ clients) with the parameters to enter.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a simple validation using this steps :

On your server side, when you receive the rest call, you have to add to your restController :

`public <YourReturn> addAClient (@Valid @RequestBody ClientDTO clientDTO)`

Then on your DTO class, you are enable to add simple check like that :

- ClientDTO

  `@NotNull(message = "<null message>")
  @Length(max = 256, message = "<max size from client Name>")
  @NotBlank(message = "<not blank message>")
  public String getName() {
      return name;
  }`

:)

Comment: thanks for your reply but I needed, for example, to convert the password to hash. I needed to override the save.

Comment: Ok. You means that you need to update the value (i.e. change the value coming from the view), so you need to create a specific method and a class for doing that.  In order to do that you need a special component/service for transforming the DTO to a "business class" **(best option**).  If you need to do only a simple modificaiton, you can create an _ENUM_ and passed it to the save method.

Comment: "Need a special component / service for transforming the DTO to a" business class "." My problem is that, I do no how to do .. any idea?

Comment: `@Service
public class ClientService{
     
     /**
      * client DTO is comming from your view
      */
     public Client transformClient (Client client){
         //Here you can transform your client.
         //Best solution is to use a clientDTO instead of a client in the method parameter
         //CLIENTDTO is the object coming from your view (html/angular...)
         
     }
}`